# Phone is not working and in fastboot device is showing as "???????????? fastboot"

Tags: rom-flashing, recovery-mode, fastboot, boot-loop, unbricking

I have a realme 2 pro and I wanted to revert it back to stock rom. I had orangefox recovery installed at the time. I tried flashing an ozip file for the device and just call it my stupidity but I the flashed that file as system image and because of that not device is not booting anymore. Both the system and recovery are inaccessible and the device when is fastboot mode shows as "????????????    fastboot". I tried to flash an recover image from fastboot but it game the folling error.
FAILED (Write to device failed (no link))
Can anyone suggest what I can do to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

1. try twrp+magisk+patch if it had bootloader unlocked
2. take it to service centre - they can restore stock rom for free